# Converting GAS array (from .gs) to javascript array (in .html)

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there an "easy" way of converting a GAS string array (in .gs file) to a javascript array that exists in an HTML file?  I'm trying to use jquery to do stuff, and it requires (from what I can tell) values to be in a javascript array.  The first piece of code is the function that gets email addresses from contacts app and returns an array of strings.  The rest are samples of HTML with a link break to separate their cajoled result (at least I'm pretty sure their cajoled result).  Also, this is basically what I'm using the availableTags variable for you'll see below:  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Script File, returns a string array of email addresses

```
function getAllContacts(){
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(ContactsApp.getContactGroup("ContactsAppTest"));
  var email = new Array();
  for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
    if(contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail() != ""){
    email.push(contacts[i].getPrimaryEmail());
    }
  }
  return email;
}
```

Try 1, create an empty js array, and manually populate from getAllContacts function.  This works, but thinking this is not very efficient.

```
var availableTags = [];
<?
var temp = getAllContacts();
for (var i=0; i<temp.length; i++) { ?>
availableTags.push(<?= temp[i] ?>);
<?} ?>

availableTags.push_m___?availableTags.push('email1@test.com'):availableTags.m___('push',['email1@test.com']);availableTags.push_m___?availableTags.push('email2@test2.com'):availableTags.m___('push',['email2@test2.com']);availableTags.push_m___?availableTags.push('email3@test3.com'):availableTags.m___('push',['email3@test3.com']);
```

Try 2, set availableTags = getAllContacts function

```
var availableTags = <?=getAllContacts()?>;

availableTags='email1@test.com,email2@test2.com,email3@test3.com'
```

Normal js array

```
var availableTags = ["email1@test.com","email2@test2.com","email3@test3.com"];

availableTags=['email1@test.com','email2@test2.com','email3@test3.com'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this out:

```
<? var temp = getAllContacts(); ?>
var availableTags = <?= temp ? "[" + temp.toString() + "]" : "null" ?>;
```

That should initialize the array on the client side all-at-once.  (I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency anyway, unless you're dealing with hundred or thousands of these contacts.  Myself, I'd shoot for what I found most readable.)

UPDATE: as noted in comment, this won't work, as the  result appears to be enquoted.
Other efforts to use `new Function()` or `eval()` on that string fail, likely due to the Caja sanitizer GAS uses on output.  This should work, instead:

```
  <? var temp = getAllContacts(); ?>

  var array = null;
  var str  = <?= temp ? temp.toString() : "" ?>;
  if(str) array = str.split(",");
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't initialize it quite right.  It looks like this:  

availableTags='[email1@test1.com,email2@test2.com,email3@test3.com]';

Each email address there should be a separate index in the array.  

And yes there will likely be thousands of these.  Unless there is a way to "mock" the gmail Send line to autocomplete based on a users contact list and/or Apps domain.

Comment: Yep, that's more like it.  Thanks!

Comment: noticed while reading docs (`https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#PullingData`), there's also a scriptlet tag that will avoid escaping and enquoting.  This should work: `var availableTags = <?!= temp ? "[" + temp.toString() + "]" : "null" ?>;`.  (for that matter, can simplify the logic to just `JSON.stringify(temp)`)